# tx_news does not fallback to right language

Tags: typo3-9.x, tx-news

I have a TYPO3 9.5 website with tx_news. Danish is the default language. I have the languages English, Romanian, Slovakian, Hungarian.
On the Romanian, Slovakian and Hungarian sites I have set the "Fallback to other Language(s) - order is important!" to English, Danish. So fx. Hungarian news should fallback to English news if not translated. But they fallback to Danish news if not translated. All news are in Danish and English.
Why does tx_news not fallback to the selected language?

From config.yaml

```
base: /
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=5'
languages:
  -
    title: Dansk
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: da
    locale: da_DK
    iso-639-1: da
    navigationTitle: DK
    hreflang: da-DK
    direction: ltr
    flag: dk
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: '2'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: EN
    hreflang: en-GB
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: gb
  -
    title: Rumænien
    enabled: true
    base: /ro/
    typo3Language: ro
    locale: ro-RO
    iso-639-1: ro
    navigationTitle: RO
    hreflang: ro-RO
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '2,0'
    flag: ro
    languageId: '3'
  -
    title: Slovakiet
    enabled: true
    base: /sk/
    typo3Language: sk
    locale: sk-SK
    iso-639-1: sk
    navigationTitle: SK
    hreflang: sk-SK
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '2,0'
    flag: sk
    languageId: '5'
  -
    title: Hungary
    enabled: true
    base: /hu/
    typo3Language: hu
    locale: hu_HU
    iso-639-1: hu
    navigationTitle: HU
    hreflang: hu_HU
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '2,0'
    flag: hu
    languageId: '6'
rootPageId: 1
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPluginDetail:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 105
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news_title: news
    defaultController: 'News::detail'
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
  NewsPluginList:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 106
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
routes: {  }
```

Comment: your site configuration would give us more information. Would you mind posting the language part of your site configuration so we will be able to help you?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Does the configuration make any sense to you?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I encountered the same problem